# Remove wrapper element in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list `<ol>` of element like this:

```
<ol class="example">
    <ol>
        <li>Dashboard</li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-user" data-toggle="popover"></i>Customer
         <ol>
            <li>Customer Contract</li>
            <li>Customer Report</li>
         </ol>
        </li>
   </ol>
</ol>
```

What I was trying to do I want want to remove the inner `<ol>` that immediately inside the `<ol class="example">`.

Therefore, the final result would be something like this:

```
<ol class="example">
        <li>Dashboard</li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-user" data-toggle="popover"></i>Customer
         <ol>
            <li>Customer Contract</li>
            <li>Customer Report</li>
         </ol>
        </li>
</ol>
```

I tried jquery function `.unwrap()` as documented in [jquery](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) as the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').find('ol.example').unwrap();
})
```

The result was nothing change. I went on trying another way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ol.example').find('ol').unwrap();
})
```

This way it removed the wrapper `<ol class="example"></ol>` instead of `<ol></ol>` element I wanted to remove.

What was going on, how can I achieve my expected result as above? Thanks.

Comment: `<ol>` can't be a direct child of `<ol>` so you need valid html to start with

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for pointing out as I did not realized that. The `<ol>` and its children inside `<ol>` of class `.example` are coming from server side got via `ajax()` called. Since it came with `ol` and it hard to modify it in server side. I decided to modify it in client side to remove that `<ol>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs,

> The `.unwrap()` method removes the element's parent. This is effectively the inverse of the `.wrap()` method. The matched elements (and their siblings, if any) replace their parents within the DOM structure.

So you'll want to do something like

```
$('ol.example').children('ol').children().unwrap();
```

or, more concisely,

```
$('ol.example > ol > *').unwrap();
```

Comment: don't use `find()` or the sub `<ol>` will also be removed

Comment: @charlietfl Good point. I've edited the answer to use `.children()` instead (and updated the concise selector as well).

Comment: Makes sense based on what is shown in question but note that is invalid markup

Comment: @drmercer Thanks very much. It works just as fine as expected.  :)

Comment: @charlietfl ~What is invalid markup?~ Ah, you must mean the nested `<ol>` . That's true. @houy-narun `ol` elements [should only have `li` children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol)

Answer (score 0):

see example:

```js
var text=$('.example>ol').html();
$('.example').html(text);

console.log($('.example').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class="example">
    <ol>
        <li>Dashboard</li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-user" data-toggle="popover"></i>Customer
         <ol>
            <li>Customer Contract</li>
            <li>Customer Report</li>
         </ol>
        </li>
   </ol>
</ol>
```